# zend session not working in class

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-session

I am using zend session, it workssetting up on the index page and if i use jquery's and check any session data. how ever within my class the session is empty?

**index.php**

```
$usersession = new Zend_Session_Namespace();
$usersession->surveyType = array("2D","3D");
$usersession->surveyTypeSelect = 'all';
```

**file i use for jquery**

```
$session = new Zend_Session_Namespace();
$log = $session->log;
$cache = $session->cache;
$surveyType = $session->surveyType;
$surveyTypeSelect = $session->surveyTypeSelect;
```

**my class**

```
$seismicLibrary = new Spectrum_Seismic_Library();
```

Any function within this class returns empty values for my saved session data.

```
public function getAllSurveysByRegionId($regionId, $published = false) {
        //'Default'
        $session = new Zend_Session_Namespace();
        $log = $session->log;
        /*foreach ($session as $index => $value) {
            $log->debug(print_r("aNamespace->$index = '$value';\n",true));
        }*/
        $surveyType = $session->surveyType;     
        $surveyTypeSelect = $session->surveyTypeSelect;
```

The above function - session data is empty.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting a new session namespace in that function rather than retrieving the one you already had. You could try creating your session, then setting it to registry using `Zend_Registry::set('session', $session)` then when you need it anywhere else you use `$session = Zend_Registry::get('session');` that way you ensure that you are using the same session namespace.

Comment: i though when you redecalre `new Zend_Session_Namespace()` if default exists it should retrieve it ?

Comment: @bonez This is directly from the documentation " if access to the session namespace is needed at a later time during the same request. For example, a developer may store the reference in a static variable, add the reference to a » registry (see Zend_Registry), or otherwise make it available to other methods that may need access to the session namespace."